# Why when I'm trying to insert into a vector of sets it's telling me "vector subscript out of range"?

Tags: c++, stl

For example

```
vector< set<int> > MY_VECTOR_SETS;
MY_VECTOR_SETS[0].insert(1);
```

I'm trying to insert number one in `MY_VECTOR_SETS` of zero.

Comment: first you need to push back a set to your vector

Comment: ... or call `resize()` before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use method resize before assigning a value to vector:

```
MY_VECTOR_SETS.resize(5) //this makes your vector resize to size of 5;
MY_VECTOR_SETS[0] = 1; //assign value 1 to first element of vector
```

Comment: Why not just do `vector< set<int> > MY_VECTOR_SETS(5);`?

Comment: yes, you can also use that when you know the size you need from the start. But if you want to use the array with fixed size, you could just use regular array and it makes your program faster.

Comment: This isn't a preference -- it's required.

Comment: well, yes. But I use vector when i need to have dynamic memory allocation and at the first declaration i use size 0.

Answer (score 0):

> Why when I'm trying to insert into a vector of sets it's telling me “vector subscript out of range”?

Because you are trying to access a set that doesn't exist in the vector.

The default constructed vector is empty. Therefore, there is no object at the zeroeth index. Trying to access the non-existing object has undefined behaviour.

Solution: Make sure that the vector contains at least one set before trying to access the first set. Perhaps the simplest way to do that is to use one of the non-default constructors that create a non-empty vector.